# I'm seeing Weird block letters instead of alphabets on login screen on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, keyboard-layout, login-screen, language-support

Last night, I've installed Nepali keyboard layout on my Ubuntu 20.04 and I tested it, it worked as expected. But, today when I switched on PC back I am getting this screen. I have tried removing the layout and rebooting PC but it didn't helped.

Pictures of the problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: At login screen type any keys and then click on eye icon.. Thats gives a clue if your login screen language is English or someother..

Comment: It shows just blocks. Like in the image shown.

Comment: Ok can you logon via tty? press CTRL+ALT+F3 or F4 or F5.. can you logon there?

Comment: Yes I can login to tty and I have tried a solution as this one 'sudo fc-cache -vf' but in tty I can go no further because idk how to use tty.

Comment: Ok when you logon via tty.. can you run this command `nano /etc/default/keyboard`. It will show you the file contents.. post those..

Comment: It outputs:XKBLAYOUT=gb
BACKSPACE=guess

Comment: is that great Britain? have you set that before the problem happend? Ok try to make the line `XKBLAYOUT=us` if your pw was set in English before. to save the file press Ctrl+O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111792/discussion-between-aakura-pyakura-and-unknown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is solved.
I had installed like 20 Nepali fonts following a tutorial on web which suggested to simply copy all *.ttf* and *.otf* files to `/usr/local/share/fonts/sample` folder *(even if there is no sample folder and creating one)*. And deleting the sample folder worked.

Thanks [UnKNOWn](https://askubuntu.com/users/739431/unknown) for all the help.